# Visual Studio only any cpu debug .exe works

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 community when building forms-applications, only when configuration is set to "Debug" and platform to "Any CPU", the generated .exe actually works. ANY OTHER configuration just doesn't run.

If I try to delete the bin-folder it says the folder is used by another program. Still nothing shows on task manager. I have to reboot to terminate it.

This happens even on empty projects so it can't be caused by my horrible coding.  I've even reinstalled Visual Studio but no luck.

I need this to work for my installer that doesn't work with "Any CPU"-config.

So how do I get all configurations to work?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: "Doesn't run" is not enough information for us to help you, please be specific about what is happening when it does not work

Comment: When I double-click the .exe, mouse gets the loading symbol if hovering the file explorer. The form doesn't show up. Nothing shows up in Task Manager. If I try to delete it, it tells me "The action can't be completed because the file is open in System".

Comment: We've been having this question asked all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Thanks. The second I uninstalled Avast all the almost running forms since the last reboot popped up. Wonder why this happens.